# How to fix default Python path after installing Virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pip

I installed virtualenv via `sudo pip install virtualenv` and created some environments. But now I'm finding my default "global" Python path is completely gone.

In a fresh terminal, I see output like:

```
user@localhost:~$ sudo pip install django
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
user@localhost:~$ ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django
bin   contrib  db        forms  __init__.py   middleware  template      test   views
conf  core     dispatch  http   __init__.pyc  shortcuts   templatetags  utils
user@localhost:~$ python
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
>>>
```

What's going on here? How do I fix my global Python installation so that it can see its installed packages?

Comment: I'm curious what happens if you run `which python`, what `sys.path` looks like inside that python, and also if `sudo python` knows about the `django` package.

Comment: @zigg, Good thinking. Those would have helped me more quickly recognize the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was my own fault. I had accidentally run `virtualenv --no-site-packages .` in my home directory, creating folders like ~/bin, ~/local, ~/lib, and Python was looking for its packages there, where there were none. Deleting these directories fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just set the environmental variable

```
PYTHONPATH=path1;path2;etc;
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

and it should use the path you specify

Comment: I know how to set my PYTHONPATH. I'm asking why is it completely gone to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

You should only install virtualenv using sudo, everything else should be done without sudo.

You should also use `--no-site-packages`, as this makes sure your environment doesn't have conflicting versions of packages.

The proper way to do this is:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages django_env
$ source django_env/bin/activate
(django_env)$ pip install -U django
```

If you need anything from your global path, you should install it in your virtual environment. That way, when you [freeze your environment](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html#freezing-requirements) you'll get only what is required for your application.

You can install [`yolk`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk), which will list packages in your environment:

```
(django_env)$ pip install yolk
(django_env)$ yolk -l
```

Comment: I don't understand the point of yolk. What does it do that `pip freeze | grep` can't do?

Comment: yolk works even if you don't have pip. There is a lot more to it than just listing packages - for example `yolk -U` checks against PyPi if there are any updates to installed packages.